# Meteor textarea saving content to collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, textarea

I'm making this webpage where you can create a canvas which includes a title and different sections on a chart. On the homepage you click "create new canvas" which calls a modal where you can enter the title of the canvas and adds it to the collection. All canvases are shown on this homepage. This feature works!

When you click on a particular canvas its routes to a new page where it displays the title of the canvas you selected and a chart for you to fill out. (Problem and solution are only two of the many parts of the chart). Currently, the title displays correctly but I'm having trouble with the textareas. The content of the textareas are not saving and when you refresh the page all of the content is erased.

```
{{title}}
<form class="js-fill-canvas">
Problem: <textarea placeholder="Top 3 problems" name="problem">{{problem}}</textarea>
Solution: <textarea placeholder="Top 3 features" name="solution">{{solution}}</textarea> 
</form>

Template.canvas_add_form.events({
  'submit .js-add-canvas':function(event){
   var title;
   title = event.target.title.value;

   Canvas.insert({
      title:title,
      createdOn: new Date(),
      createdBy: Meteor.user()._id
   });
   $("#canvas_add_form").modal('hide');
   return false;
   }
});

Template.canvas_edit.events({
   'submit .js-fill-canvas':function(event){ 
    var problem, solution;
    problem = $(event.target).val();
    solution = $(event.target).val();

    Canvas.insert({
       problem:problem,
       solution:solution
    });
    return false;
    }
});
```

The only difference between the canvas_add_form and the canvas_edit is that the add form is using input instead of textarea. Is it incorrect to insert into the collection a second time?

Comment: The first insert creates a new mongodb record. The second insert, like the first, inserts another mongodb record. Is this what you want? Or do you first want to create a record in mongo the first time you submit the 'add' form and then subsequently pull up the same mongo record and edit it and add extra attributes to the same mongo record using the 'edit' form?

Comment: Yeah, so I don't want to create a new record I just want to add to the first collection and when I pull up the 'edit' form all the information is there. I tried  implementing the code below by jordanwillis and it seems to be a step in the right direction however, when I leave and reenter the edit form, all the information previously written is no longer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved! I needed to set all variables within the object to undefined the first time creating the object. Afterwards when updating the object, I was then able to set textarea values to the empty variables. Here's the working code:

```
{{title}}
<form class="js-fill-canvas">
Problem: <textarea placeholder="Top 3 problems" id="problem">{{problem}}</textarea>
Solution: <textarea placeholder="Top 3 features" id="solution">{{solution}}</textarea> 
</form>

Template.canvas_add_form.events({
  'submit .js-add-canvas':function(event){
   var title, problem, solution;
   title = event.target.title.value;

   Canvas.insert({
      title:title,
      problem: undefined,
      solution: undefined,
      createdOn: new Date(),
      createdBy: Meteor.user()._id
   });
   $("#canvas_add_form").modal('hide');
   return false;
   }
});

Template.canvas_edit.events({
   'submit .js-fill-canvas':function(event){ 

    problem = $('textarea#problem').val();
    solution = $('textarea#solution').val();

    Canvas.update(this._id,{ 
       $set: {
       problem:problem,
       solution:solution
       }
    });
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is a problem to insert twice because you are then saving the textarea data into a brand new record (which doesn't seem to make sense).

Instead, you should just update your record like this.

```
Template.canvas_edit.events({ 
  'submit .js-fill-canvas': function(event) { 
    var problem, solution;
    problem = event.target.problem.value; 
    solution = event.target.solution.value;

    Canvas.update(this._id, {
      $set: {
        problem: problem, 
        solution: solution 
      }
    }); 

    return false; 
  }
});
```

Some key things here is that `this` contains the data context from your template (so we can get our _id) and you can directly access form elements from `event.target`

Comment: Hi thank you! This makes a lot of sense and is definitely what I needed to implement in my code. However, when I leave the page and reenter the edit form, any text that I have filled in the textareas are no longer there. {{problem}} and {{solution}} are not accessing the information, or I am not setting the information in the collection in the first place.

Comment: @Court it's hard to say what could be the problem without seeing more code. I would validate that the document is in fact updated (check from mongdb shell). If so then check your publish/subscribe logic. Perhaps if you provide a full end to end example I can point out the issue. I would want to see all the js for canvas_add_form and canvas_edit_form (not just the event handlers). Also, add a console.log in your event handlers to make sure they are firing too. Also, if you aren't using the insecure package then check your Canvas allow/deny rules to make sure docs can be updated from client.

Comment: the files are quite lengthy, can I possibly send you a zip file over email?

Comment: @Court If you can add it to github (or similar) then I will take a look at it.

Comment: no need! I finally solved the issue and I posted my answer above. Thank you for your help though! You definitely helped guide me in the right direction.